# Replace character in a string with space

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need the following output in SQL server 2008

problem is to remove numbers from string

i.e column name is `associated_id` which is `nvarchar` type and value could be `(23,34,45)`
But I want the following result (23,45).

Comment: set Value = replace(value,',34','') - this is the way you would do it on an update - see if you can work out how to adapt it to a query!

Comment: please provide schema and data samples.

Answer (score 0):

May this help

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAlphabetFromAlphaNumeric]

    (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(500))

    RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
        END
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)

END
```